# Nested if and Formula

Tags: excel-formula

HI i am trying to write the IF function like this.

```
=IF(AND(E3="Epyllion",J3="7"),".70","")
```

But result always shows 0 instead of .70.

My point for this function is,

```
IF E3="Epyllion" AND J3="7" Then .70 AND IF E3="Epyllion" AND J3="5" Then ".72" AND IF E3="Epyllion" AND J3="3" Then ".80"
```

Can someone help me to write this formula.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula works for me.

IF(AND(E3="Epyllion",J3=7),70,IF(AND(E3="Epyllion",J3=5),72,IF(AND(E3="Epyllion",J3=3),80,"NULL")))

Answer (score 0):

Your formula should have been

```
=IF(AND(E3="Epyllion",J3=7),".70","")
```

unless `Cell J3` is formatted as text.

With all the conditions mentioned in the question formula can be written as

```
=IF(E3="Epyllion",IF(J3=7,".70",IF(J3=5,".72","0.8")))
```

provided you just have `7,3,5` for `Cell J3`. If you have more than these three values then use

```
=IF(E3="Epyllion",IF(J3=7,".70",IF(J3=5,".72",IF(J3=3,".80",""))),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in `F2` cell

```
=IF(AND(E2="Epyllion",J2=9),".90",
  IF(AND(E2="Epyllion",J2=7),".70",
  IF(AND(E2="Epyllion",J2=5),".50",
  IF(AND(E2="Epyllion",J2=3),".30",""))))
```

[image]